# Remove a specific field

Tags: entities

In my backend, I have an error "node.field_descriptif need to uninstall", but I don't have this field anymore, but it is in the database. How can I do that?

EDIT :

I tried

> drush entup

This is showing me entity that needs to be updated, but when I try to press yes, I have this error :

> The command could not be executed successfully (returned:
>   'C:/MAMP/htdocs/ext-partenaires/vendor/drush/drush/drush' n’est pas
>   reconnu en tant que commande interne ou externe, un programme
>   exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

But drush is working if I do for example a "drush cr" (my variable is set to C:\MAMP\htdocs\ext-partenaires\vendor\bin), even if I set a variable to the expected path

Comment: Which drush version are you using? Is it installed globally? Also, which drupal version? Did you install it via composer?

Comment: Drush 9, Drupal 8.5.4, yes it's installed globaly and via composer.